# Property 'charVar' does not exist on type 'HttpService'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in a D&D character creator for fun and knowledge but I'm having some issues with my service here, apparently the TS compiler have some issues with my instanciation of 'CharacterVariables':

```
ERROR in src/app/components/httpGet.service.ts:15:18 - error TS2339: Property 'charVar' does not exist on type 'HttpService'.

    15             this.charVar.races = response;
                        ~~~~~~~
    src/app/components/httpGet.service.ts:24:18 - error TS2339: Property 'charVar' does not exist on type 'HttpService'.

    24             this.charVar.raceInfo = response;
```

this is the service file that it's refering to:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CharacterVariables } from "./CharacterVariables";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(charVar: CharacterVariables, protected http: HttpClient) { }

  //Get races in Character data
  getRaces(route) {
    this.http.get(route).subscribe(response => {
            this.charVar.races = response;
        }, err => {
            throw err;
        });
  }

  //Get the information of the selected race
  getRaceInfo(route) {
    this.http.get(route).subscribe(response => {
            this.charVar.raceInfo = response;
        }, err => {
            throw err;
        });
  }
}
```

And this is the file of the global variables that I'm trying to use in the service (CharacterVariables):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CharacterVariables {

  name: string = '';
  surname: string = '';

  gender: string = '';

  races: object = {};
  race: string = '';
  raceInfo: object = {};
}
```

I'm not sure why TS is not compiling this because if I tinker a bit with the files (change something minimal, save and undo the change and save again) the page actually shows up and the code is working as intended, so I'm kind of confused with this one. Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access the property you need to declare your constructor like this:

```
 constructor(private charVar: CharacterVariables, protected http: HttpClient) { }
```

Notice how I have added the `private` keyword

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier in the constructor is a shortcut for variable definition using Typescript [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties). In short, writing

```js
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private charVar: CharacterVariables) { }
}
```

is equivalent to writing

```js
export class HttpService {
  private charVar: CharacterVariables;
  constructor(charVar: CharacterVariables) {
    this.charVar = charVar;
  }
}
```

So if the access modifier isn't mentioned, there is no member variable  `charVar` in the class.